# Import Scripts From Folders Dynamically in For Loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have my `main.py` script in a folder, along with about 10 other folders with varying names. These names change from time to time so I can't just import by a specific folder name each time; so I thought I could create a `For` loop that would dynamically load all the folder names into a list first, then iterate over them to import the `template.py` script that is within each folder. And yes, they are all named template.py, but each folder has one that is unique to that folder.

My `main.py` script looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

# All items in the current directory that do not have a dot extension, and isn't the pycache folder,
# are considered folders to iterate through
pipeline_folder_names = [name for name in os.listdir("./") if not '.' in name and not 'pycache' in name]

for i in pipeline_folder_names:
    print(i)
    path = sys.path.insert(0, './' + i)
    import template
```

It works on the first folder just fine, but then doesn't change into the next directory to import the next template script. I've tried adding both:

```
os.chdir('../')
```

and

```
sys.path.remove('./' + i)
```

to the end to "reset" the directory but neither of them work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a module in python, it's loaded into the cache. The second time you import `template`, its not the new file that's imported, python just reloads the first one.

This is what worked for me.

The directory structure and content:

```
.
├── 1
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── template.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── template.py
├── 2
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── template.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── template.py
└── temp.py

$ cat 1/template.py
print("1")
$ cat 2/template.py
print("2")
```

Load the first one manualy, then use the `reload` function from `importlib` to load the new `template.py` file.

```py
import os
import sys
import importlib

# All items in the current directory that do not have a dot extension, and isn't the pycache folder,
# are considered folders to iterate through
pipeline_folder_names = [name for name in os.listdir("./") if not '.' in name and not 'pycache' in name]

sys.path.insert(1, './' + pipeline_folder_names[0])
import template
sys.path.remove('./' + pipeline_folder_names[0])

for i in pipeline_folder_names[1:]:
    path = sys.path.insert(0, './' + i)
    importlib.reload(template)
    sys.path.remove('./' + i)
```

Running this give the output:

```
$ python temp.py
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

considering the above folder structure.

> You need to create each folder a module, which can done by creating an
>   empty
>   `__init__.py` file in each folder parallel to template.py

then below code in temp.py will solve your issue

```
import os
import sys
import importlib

pipeline_folder_names = [name for name in os.listdir("./") if not '.' in name and not 'pycache' in name]

def import_template(directory):
    importlib.import_module(directory+'.template')


for i in pipeline_folder_names:
    import_template(i)
```